# Throw and ternary operator in C++

Tags: c++, operators, ternary-operator

The following code compiles with G++ 4.6.1, but not with Visual Studio 2008

```
return (m_something == 0) ? 
    throw std::logic_error("Something wrong happened") : m_something;
```

The fact is the Visual Studio compiler performs an internal crash.

I want to know if this is standard C++ and why it doesn't compile with Visual Studio, but does with G++?

Comment: Regardless of this being valid code or not according to the standard, when a compiler crashes with an internal compiler error (which is what VC does, IIUC), then that is an error in the compiler. A compiler is supposed to emit a meaningful message even for faulty code, not a crash report.

Comment: Keep in mind this is the *conditional operator*, which happens to be *a* ternary operator.

Comment: Yeah, got confused when "ternary" wasn't in the spec anywhere.

Comment: For a brief period (between c++11 and c++14) throwing from a ternary was the only way to write constexpr functions that could fail at compile-time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is standard C++.  Either (or both) of the then/else expressions in a conditional expression is allowed to be a throw-expression instead (C++98 5.16/2).

If Visual Studio crashes when compiling it... that would seem to be unfortunate!

Comment: §5.16/2 allows both expressions to be throw expressions in C++11.

Comment: @Mat: oops, you're quite right, the text here is unchanged, and the second alternative allows for both to be throws in C++98 too.

Answer (score 4):

Comeau compiles it without errors (here's my minimal compilable test case):

```
int main(void)
{
    int x = 17;
    return x ? throw "Something wrong happened" : 5;
}
```

which is pretty good evidence that it's allowed by the standard.  So is the fact that MSVC crashes, rather than failing cleanly with an error.

Also, it appears to be fixed in VC++ 2010

```
R:\>cl ternarythrowtest.cpp
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.40219.01 for 80x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

ternarythrowtest.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 10.00.40219.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:ternarythrowtest.exe
ternarythrowtest.obj
```

and x64 version:

```
R:\>cl ternarythrowtest.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.40219.01 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

ternarythrowtest.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 10.00.40219.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:ternarythrowtest.exe
ternarythrowtest.obj
```

Upgrade your compiler if possible, this is far from the only bug fixed in 2010.

Comment: Indeed, this is probably because of C++11 compliance, see @MooingDuck's answer.

Comment: @AndréCaron: That fails to explain an "Internal Compiler Error".  And see John's answer, it's allowed in C++98 as well.

Comment: I'm on @fmorency's team, and I'm the one who encountered the Microsoft Compiler crash with his throw-in-a-ternary-operator expression.  We were trying to figure out if it was standard, not if this is a bug in Microsoft's compiler (there is obviously *a* bug, since it crashes).

Comment: @AndréCaron: Well, it's C++98, not a C++11 compliance issue, so it's definitely supposed to work.

Comment: Indeed :-).  Unfortunately, we're stuck with Qt 4.7 at the moment and we support Windows, so we're stuck with VS2008's compiler.

Comment: @AndréCaron: How does that prevent you from moving to 2010?

Comment: VS2010 is not officially supported by Qt 4.7, and someone higher up the food chain decided we were sticking to "officially supported" solutions.

Answer (score 4):

From the C++11 February Draft

> § 5.16/2 If either the second or the third operand has type (possibly cv-qualified) void, then the lvalue-to-rvalue (4.1), array-to-pointer (4.2), and function-to-pointer (4.3) standard conversions are performed on the second and third operands, and one of the following shall hold:
>   — The second or the third operand (but not both) is a throw-expression (15.1); the result is of the type of the other and is a prvalue.
>   — Both the second and the third operands have type void; the result is of type void and is a prvalue. [ Note: This includes the case where both operands are throw-expressions. —end note ]

It appears that `throw` counts as evaluating to a `void`, and that this is allowed.

Comment: C++11 is scarcely relevant to VS2008 (except that this isn't a C++11 rule, it's unchanged since C++98, see John's answer).

Comment: I don't have a copy of the C++03 draft (for VS2008) to quote from, or I would have quoted from that instead.  You're right that it didn't necessarily apply to VS2008 however.

Answer (score 2):

The internal crash can be considered a bug of Visual Studio. A compiler should never crash because of the code being compiled.

This is a very strange usage of the ternary operator, a simple if before the return would be a much preferable idiom:

```
if(m_something == 0)
    throw std::logic_error("Something wrong happened");

return m_something;
```