# Throw new exception in Ternary condition

Tags: java, ternary-operator

I have this lines of code:

```
List<Long> list = new ArrayList<>();

if (n < 0) throw new RuntimeException();

if (n == 0) return list;
```

I want to use `Ternary condition` :

```
return (n < 0) ? (throw new RuntimeException()) : list;
```

But i have compile time exception.

Comment: This is not possible with the ternary operator. You'll have to use `if` instead.

Comment: I think it is supposed to be operations in all the three. throws is not an operation.

Comment: @ryekayo I have compile time error, `illegal start of expression`

Comment: Another dup: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19010399/1065197

Comment: For people falling in this question looking for a C++ answer. This is allowed in C++, either or both options in a ternary operator is allowed to `throw`. Maybe this is the origin of the confusion. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957696/throw-and-ternary-operator-in-c

Comment: You can if you want to abuse the language a little: `public static <T> T throwException(RuntimeException e) { throw e; }` _pretends_ to return a value of the expected type, satisfying the compiler, but throws an exception instead. In use: `return (n < 0) ? throwException(new RuntimeException()) : list;`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can't throw an exception in a ternary clause. Both options must return a value, which `throw new Exception();` doesn't satisfy.

Solution, use `if`.

Comment: Actually, the reason of that depends on how languages treat their language constructs:
* In C++, throw is an expression, as such, it may appear as a term of an expression, thus inside the ternary operator ? aka ?: which is an expression. However, an if is statement and can't appear in the middle of an expression.
* In functional languages, the if usually encompasses both the if and ternary operator, as the if is an expression (implying btw that the else clause is mandatory). Throws are therefore usually expressions as well.
* In Java, though, a throw is (sadly) a statement. This is why...

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't compile because what you want to do is not legal in Java. 
You can't return `throw new RuntimeException()`. Your return always have to return a value.

You have to use if instead of that.